# Linker's Error while using ShapeShifter

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting linker's error while try to use ShapeShifter for getting size of  ROS topic. Here is code:-

```
void topicCallback(const ShapeShifter::ConstPtr &msg, const std::string &topic_name)
{
  uint32_t length = msg->size();
  sizes+=length;

  auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  double diff = std::chrono::duration<double>(time-last).count();
  last=time;
  times+=diff;
}

ros::init(argc, argv, "universal_subscriber");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  boost::function<void(const ShapeShifter::ConstPtr &)> callback;
  callback = [topic_name](const ShapeShifter::ConstPtr &msg)
  {
    topicCallback(msg, topic_name);
  };
  
  ros::Subscriber subscriber = nh.subscribe(topic_name, 10, callback);
```

Error Message:

```
tp.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `topic_tools::ShapeShifter::size() const'
CMakeFiles/roshz.dir/src/tp.cpp.o: In function `ros::serialization::PreDeserialize<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>::notify(ros::serialization::PreDeserializeParams<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> const&)':
tp.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros13serialization14PreDeserializeIN11topic_tools12ShapeShifterEE6notifyERKNS0_20PreDeserializeParamsIS3_EE[_ZN3ros13serialization14PreDeserializeIN11topic_tools12ShapeShifterEE6notifyERKNS0_20PreDeserializeParamsIS3_EE]+0x243): undefined reference to `topic_tools::ShapeShifter::morph(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/roshz.dir/src/tp.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>::type boost::make_shared<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>()':
tp.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11make_sharedIN11topic_tools12ShapeShifterEJEEENS_6detail15sp_if_not_arrayIT_E4typeEDpOT0_[_ZN5boost11make_sharedIN11topic_tools12ShapeShifterEJEEENS_6detail15sp_if_not_arrayIT_E4typeEDpOT0_]+0x77): undefined reference to `topic_tools::ShapeShifter::ShapeShifter()'
CMakeFiles/roshz.dir/src/tp.cpp.o: In function `ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<topic_tools::ShapeShifter const> const&, void>::getTypeInfo()':
tp.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11topic_tools12ShapeShifterEEEvE11getTypeInfoEv[_ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11topic_tools12ShapeShifterEEEvE11getTypeInfoEv]+0xb): undefined reference to `typeinfo for topic_tools::ShapeShifter'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(roshz)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
)

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
  )

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${catkin_DEFINITIONS})

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  src/roshz.cpp
  src/statistics.cpp
  src/tp.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387669/linker%27s-error-while-using-shapeshifter/) by [Aakin](https://answers.ros.org/users/85955/aakin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-09-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-29**:
Can you show the error pls

**Comment by [Aakin](https://answers.ros.org/users/85955/aakin/) on 2021-09-29**:
tp.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `topic_tools::ShapeShifter::size() const' CMakeFiles/roshz.dir/src/tp.cpp.o: In function` ros::serialization::PreDeserialize<topic_tools::ShapeShifter>::notify(ros::serialization::PreDeserializeParams<topic_tools::ShapeShifter> const&)':
tp.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros13serialization14PreDeserializeIN11topic_tools12ShapeShifterEE6notifyERKNS0_20PreDeserializeParamsIS3_EE[_ZN3ros13serialization14PreDeserializeIN11topic_tools12ShapeShifterEE6notifyERKNS0_20PreDeserializeParamsIS3_EE]+0x243): undefined reference to `topic_tools::ShapeShifter::morph(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' CMakeFiles/roshz.dir/src/tp.cpp.o: In function` boost::detail

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-29**:
Check this answer #q292757. It’s similar. Hope it helps

**Comment by [Aakin](https://answers.ros.org/users/85955/aakin/) on 2021-09-29**:
I am unable to understand the solution.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-29**:
I just read your comment. Take a look at this answer #q197132 is about linker errors. It’s getting late here. Hope it helps and will check tomorrow morning

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-30**:
Linker errors are commonly caused by libraries / packages which are not linked against. That's all configured in your `CMakeLists.txt`. You don't show that in your question, so we can't help you.

Also: please add the actual, full, error message to your question. Not in a comment.

**Comment by [Aakin](https://answers.ros.org/users/85955/aakin/) on 2021-09-30**:
@gvdhoorn I have updated my question and included my  CMakeLists.txt and entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ShapeShifter` is in `topic_tools`, not `roscpp`. You're not linking against the required libraries.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aakin](https://answers.ros.org/users/85955/aakin/) on 2021-09-30**:
Thanks a lot